# How can I cast an IQueryable to a custom interface?

Tags: c#

I was struggling to cast IQueryable to a custom interface that I created in C#.

I was looking inside the Queryable class to see how it works and I figure out that IQueryable can be casted to IOrderedQueryable easily, just doing this inside OrderBy method;

```
(IOrderedQueryable<TSource>) source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>( 
            Expression.Call(
                null,
                GetMethodInfo(Queryable.OrderBy, source, keySelector),
                new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(keySelector) }
                ));
```

and when I do the same, it doesn't work.

For example:

What I was trying to do:

```
public interface ISelectQuery : IQueryable { }
public interface ISelectQuery<out T> : IQueryable<T>, ISelectQuery { }


internal static ISelectQuery<T> Select<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> propSelector)
{
    if (query == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return (ISelectQuery<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(
       Expression.Call(
           GetMethodInfo(QueryBuilder.Select<T>, query, propSelector),
           new Expression[] { query.Expression, propSelector }
       )
    );        
}
```

I can't figure out where what I'm doing wrong.

I was doing that because I was trying to do the same idea as IOrderedQueryable, when ThenBy is only available after I call OrderBy method.

Can anyone help me to understand that please?

Comment: Why do you have the `ISelectQuery` interface or why do you want to create it? What is wrong with `IQueryable`? Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: well, there's nothing wrong with the IQueryable.
the ISelectQuery is a example, i want to create something like that cuz i wanna create one custom method like update, but i want it to be avaliable after the Where Method is called for example.

Comment: You are spelling some of your methods wrong. `ISelecQuery` needs a `t`

Comment: @RicardoMelo That sounds like an XY problem. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description what you are actually trying to do and how it affects the `Where()` extension method (or any other LINQ extension method).